# Time Machine backup interval in Sierra does not appear to work

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

Apple seems to keep modifying the behavior of Time Machine in small steps.
In El Capitan (OS X 10.11), SIP changed the ability to directly modify certain system files/directories, however, with SIP disabled, it was still possible to modify these files.
Time machine used /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-auto.plist and
object named "Interval". 
In Sierra (MacOS 10.12), Time Machine seems to be ignoring the value of Interval and still performs a backup once an hour. Since, as of this writing, Sierra is still beta, this may be premature, but does anyone know if (and how) the mechanism for determining the backup interval has changed? Thank you in advance.